# What is the difference between vasoconstriction and contractility?

Tags: terminology, cardiovascular-disease, cortisol, vasoconstriction

I was reading few articles that mention stress induced cortisol may contribute to vasoconstriction and contractility as if they are different.  I did some searches on vasoconstriction and contractility but I kept getting the somewhat similar explanations of narrowing blood vessels and hence raising blood pressure. Could someone help explain and differentiate the two?

Comment: Although this has fairly low level of prior research, I decided to answer it.

Answer (score 7):

Although the term "contractility" can refer to contraction of any muscle, including skeletal muscle (e.g. biceps) and smooth muscle (e.g. muscles in arterial walls), in medicine **contractility usually refers to [cardiac contractility](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK54085/)**, which in most fundamental terms is the **force with which the heart muscle squeezes.**

According to the [textbook Regulation of Cardiac Contractility by Solaro](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK54078/):

> Contractility describes the relative ability of the heart to eject a
>   stroke volume (SV) at a given prevailing afterload (arterial pressure)
>   and preload (end-diastolic volume; EDV).

[Vasoconstriction](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/002338.htm) is a specific term for the squeezing of smooth muscle within the walls of blood vessels (arteries, arteroiles, veins, venuoles, etc).  Vasoconstriction of arteries increases arterial blood pressure and [cardiac afterload](https://www.cvpharmacology.com/vasoconstrictor/vasoconstrictor).  Vasoconstriction of veins increases venous return to the heart by reducing venous pooling, thus [increasing preload](https://www.cvpharmacology.com/vasoconstrictor/vasoconstrictor).  Of note, most often vasoconstriction is used to refer to *arterial* vasoconstriction.  There is a lot of good information on the pharmacology of modulating blood pressure including vasopressors (norepinephrine, levophed) that vasoconstrict to raise blood pressure in septic or hemorrhagic shock, etc.

Cortisol both [increases cardiac contractility](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4568128/) *as well as* [increases arterial vasoconstriction](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15320828).

Both increasing cardiac contractility (increased force of squeezing blood out of the heart) as well as increasing arterial vasoconstriction (decreasing diameter of arteries) will raise blood pressure.